# How to Get Max Value and Return Other Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have master table similar to this

```
ID     | Location | Quantity in Inventory
-----------------------------------------    
ID1000 | LOC01    | 0    
ID1000 | LOC02    | 10    
ID2000 | LOC02    | 10
```

one ID could be located in different locations and one location could had multiple IDs

There are tasks to query location with the rules of ID must be same and Qty in Inventory is higher than requested. Therefore i created an excel table to do that

```
ID | Qty Requested | Location
```

However I failed when using vlookup because it ended up getting the first value from master table which could lead to less quantity than requested. I have tried index match but failed to get the location.

What is the best way so that when there is a request of id ID1000 and quantity 5, it shows the result of location LOC02 instead of LOC01?

Appreciate the help, first time posting, sorry english is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:B4,MATCH(1,(A2:A4=G2)*(C2:C4=H2),0))
```

[image]